# Send a short signal to the audio jack of fixed frequency

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8

I want to send a short signal with a fixed frequency of 15 000 HZ to the audio jack. That will be feasible on the Windows Phone 8 platform?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: I am intersted in how to make that possible. Not for now

Comment: did you check this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882455.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate any sound you want on Windows Phone 8.
If user has something attached to the audiojack, device will send sound there.
If there is nothing, device will play the sound on speaker.
Sending sound only to jack and not to speaker is not possible, from what I know.

The easiest way to generate custom sound is to follow this article from Charles Petzold and create custom media source:
as **seshuk** suggested: 
[Musical Instruments for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882455.aspx)
or 
[Streaming Audio in Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852599.aspx)

**Update:**
Hey, I found an article on [developer.nokia.com on how to detect if headset is attached to the device](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_detect_if_an_headset_is_plugged)